# read specific files names in adf pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse

I have got requirement saying, blob storage has multiple files with names file_1.csv,file_2.csv,file_3.csv,file_4.csv,file_5.csv,file_6.csv,file_7.csv. From these i have to read only filenames from 5 to 7.

how we can achieve this in ADF/Synapse pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have repro’d in my lab, please see the below repro steps.

**ADF:**

1. Using the `Get Metadata` activity, get a list of all files.

(Parameterize the source file name in the source dataset to pass ‘*’ in the dataset parameters to get all files.)

[image]

Get Metadata output:

[image]

2. Pass the Get Metadata output **child items** to `ForEach` activity.

   `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

3. Add `If Condition` activity inside ForEach and add the **true** case expression to copy only required files to sink.

`@and(greater(int(substring(item().name,4,1)),4),lessOrEquals(int(substring(item().name,4,1)),7))`

[image]

4. When the If Condition is True, add `copy data` activity to copy the current item (file) to sink.

Source:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Niharika but I have to do it with one activity not multiple activities

Answer (score 0):

You can always do what @NiharikaMoola-MT suggested . But since you already know the range of the files ( 5-7) , I suggest

1. Declare two paramter as an upper and lower range
2. Create a Foreach loop and pass the parameter and to create a range[lowerlimit,upperlimit]
3. Create a paramterized dataset for source .
4. Use the fileNumber from the FE loop to create a dynamic expression like

> @concat('file',item(),'.csv')

Comment: I have to do it with one activity not multiple activities

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approaching using a Filter activity and the `endsWith` function:

[image]

The filter expression is:

```
@or(or(endsWith(item().name, '_5.csv'),endsWith(item().name, '_6.csv')),endsWith(item().name, '_7.csv'))
```

Slightly different approaches, similar results, it depends what you need.

Comment: I have to do it with one activity only not multiple activities

Comment: This seems like a strange constraint to have - why one activity?  It does not make sense given ADF is a framework of multiple components you can glue together.  A notebook might be able to do this in 'one' activity but you would need many lines of code, eg Python or Scala